# Is there a way to use an actual MVC view and model to create an Html file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razorengine

There are a couple of "requirements":

1) The application must generate static HTML files from razor markup.

2) The controller in achieving (1), needs to use views and models that are already defined in application.

I understand that [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) can combine a trivial template and a model as a string containing Html:

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";   
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

The documentation doesn't say much but the issue here is that this doesn't go far enough. I want the Parse method to either accept:

a) the name of a view known to the controller or

b) the path of the view.

Is there a way to use an actual MVC view and model to create an Html file? A working example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> b) the path of the view.

If you know the path of the view, you could read its contents:

```
string viewPath = "...";
string template = File.ReadAllText(viewPath);
```

and then as the documentation states you could use the Razor Engine to pass a model and the contents of the view to get the markup:

```
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

Comment: I thought about doing that but thought it would be more complex. I didn't think it would be able to work out the using statements, etc. So, I posted the problem on here before I even tried it.

Comment: It would be nice if I could get the path of the view from the context. I'll have a quick look.